# Вводные слова в присоединительных конструкциях

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, вводные-слова

Непонятна логика примеров у Розенталя.

> Многие художники, и главным образом Айвазовский, посвятили своё творчество изображению моря.

Айвазовский — один из тех многих художников.

> В странах Запада и, особенно, в США массовая безработица достигала порой рекордных размеров.

США — страна Запада, то есть по идее тоже присоединительная конструкция, но почему-то обособление другое. Почему?

Это как сказать: *Родители и, особенно, мама не разрешали мне в детстве гулять допоздна.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наречия и вводные слова (особенно, в особенности, например и т.д.) могут стоять в начале обособленного оборота, но при этом сам оборот должен обособляться по каким-либо правилам. Если речь идет об уточняющих оборотах, **то уточняющий член предложения входит в состав уточняемого**, и это надо проверить.

В том числе такая проверка необходима **при наличии союза "и"**, который может относиться к обособленной конструкции или к структуре предложения. (см. п.3 у Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120 )

1) Многие художники, и главным образом Айвазовский, посвятили своё творчество изображению моря. (Айвазовский отнесен ко многим художникам).

2) В странах Запада и, особенно, в США массовая безработица достигала порой рекордных размеров. (А вот здесь не всё ясно).

Этот пример объяснен у Розенталя.  Но вопрос состоит  в том, **какие страны относить к странам Запада**, а он в разное время  решался по-разному.

Если считать, что США относится к Западу, то пунктуацию надо изменить: *В странах Запада, и особенно в США, массовая безработица достигала порой рекордных размеров.*

3) А вот мама точно относится к родителям:

Родители, и особенно мама, не разрешали мне в детстве гулять допоздна.

Comment: Скажите, а почему сочетание _главным образом_ не обособляется внутри присоединительной конструкции? Его ведь можно переставить: "Многие художники, и Айвазовский главным образом, посвятили своё творчество изображению моря". Также удивляют предложения с сочетанием _в частности_: "Руководители Союза писателей, и в частности я, несут ответственность...". Можно же написать: "Руководители Союза писателей, и я в частности, несут ответственность...". Союз не тесно примыкает к вводному.

Comment: Вводное слово с присоединительным значением может находиться не только в начале, но в КОНЦЕ обособленного оборота  Розенталь: п.14 http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122   НАПРИМЕР находясь в начале или конце оборота, выделяется запятыми вместе с ним: Даже в городах, например в Москве, ...Вопросом заинтересовались и другие, я например;

Comment: Прочитайте, пожалуйста, снова мой вопрос. Он заключается в другом — в том, почему союз тесно примыкает к вводному сочетанию, если это сочетание можно оторвать от него и переместить.

Comment: Вводные слова и наречия используются в качестве присоединительных союзов, без них предложение некорректно: (Нельзя сказать: Многие художники, Айвазовский, посвятили своё творчество изображению моря).

Comment: То есть присоединительным союзом является всё сочетание "и главным образом" (в предложении с Айвазовским) и "и особенно" (в предложении с мамой)?

Comment: Да, верно. Ведь союз И также может иметь присоединительное значение, а здесь мы имеем сочетание союз+ наречие-конкретизатор .